# Importing file-loader directly in entry point of app (webpack). What is the exclamation point?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-file-loader

I'm using a React template and I am currently very confused by this one line, for multiple reasons.

```
require('file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./index.html');
```

1. First, why is file-loader being required in the entry point app file?
2. What is the `name=[name]` parameter doing?
3. What does the exclamation point mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a Webpack loader (in this case `file-loader`) being [used inline](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline).

When a Webpack loader is used inline, rather than via an object in a Webpack configuration file's `module.rules` array, the name of the loader to be used is prepended to the name of the file you want to require (or import), separated by a `!`. Any options to be passed to the loader are specified after the loader's name as either a query string or a JSON string, with a `?` separating the loader name and loader options.

Given that [`file-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) copies a file to your Webpack output directory and returns its URL, `require("file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./index.html")` copies `./index.html` to the output directory with its original name and extension. If the result of calling `require` was assigned to any variable, in this case it would return `/index.html` (prefixed with a public path if set in your Webpack configuration file).

All of this is Webpack specific - if you tried to run this code in Node.js without putting it through Webpack, you would almost certainly get an error.